# How do I use a different AWS endpoint with another AWS region?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using AWS recognition on an S3 bucket of data that is currently located in the US-West-1 region. Unfortunately, AWS Rekognition is not supported in that region. I attempted to copy over my bucket into a US-West-2 region, but encountered difficulties in getting metadata. As such, my question is, how do I route my API call to another endpoint, specifically the endpoint 'https://rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' even though the bucket is based in another region. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: I thought it may be relevant to mention, I am running this on Python.

Comment: How are you trying to access AWS Rekognition?

Comment: I am using an API call in a Python script, using the search_faces_by_image command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using boto3 in your python script, you should be able to select a region when you create your [client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client) resource. Try doing something similar to this:

```
re_client= boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='us-east-1')
```

If your question is if you can use AWS Rekognition in one region to access a bucket in another region: As far as I know, you can't. However, you might be able to either migrate yor bucket to the specific region, or use [S3 cross-region recplication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) to access the data from both regions.

Comment: When I change the region, the script fails, even if I am using a bucket within said region. It seemed to me that the easier alternative would be to change the endpoint rather than the region itself. Is that possible? Or does the region automatically decide the endpoint location?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you are trying to achieve. I updated my answer

Comment: By specifying the region, the endpoint is selected. However, the SDK does support specifying the endpoint but I don't remember what it is.